# Pandas chain.from_iterable: Error object of type 'itertools.chain' has no len()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Having a dataframe as the following:

```
df_data=pd.DataFrame({'name':[['ABC','DOS','TRES'],['XYZ','MORTGAGE','SOLUTIONS']],
                      'original': ['ABC DOS TRES','XYZ MORTGAGE SOLUTIONS']})
```

I am using chain.from_iterable to extract every item in a list and add the result to a dataframe:

```
s = pd.DataFrame(chain.from_iterable(df_data['name']),columns=['word'])
```

How can I do something like this:

```
t = pd.DataFrame({'word': chain.from_iterable(df_data['name'])})
```

The last creation of dataframe is giving an error `TypeError: object of type 'itertools.chain' has no len()`. What is the difference between both dataframe creations? How the error in the last creation can be fixed?

Thanks :)

Comment: if your data is already in your dataframe as a list then just do `df.explode('name')` if your pandas version is 0.25+

Comment: `t` works for me, perhaps this is an issue < 0.25.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `chain.from_iterable` returns an iterator, not a list/sequence.  Older versions of Pandas needs the objects you pass to the data frame constructor to have a `len` so it knows what size array to allocate on the backend.  The `chain` object does not supply that (nor should it).

You can wrap it in `list` is solve your issue:

```
t = pd.DataFrame({'word': list(chain.from_iterable(df_data['name']))})
```

Comment: It should work for newer version of pandas. `chain`, `map`, `filter` and other generators are all supported now.

Answer (score 2):

You can also just use a list comprehension.

```
>>> pd.DataFrame({'word': [w for group in df_data['name'] for w in group]})
        word
0        ABC
1        DOS
2       TRES
3        XYZ
4   MORTGAGE
5  SOLUTIONS
```